# Elegant solution to echo to either stdout or file in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout

I have a bash application that is producing some result, and I'd like to echo the result to either `stdout` or to a user chosen file. Because I also echo other interactive messages going to the screen, requiring the user to explicitly use the `>` redirection when he wants to echo the result to a file is not an option (*), as those messages would also appear in the file.

Right now I have a solution, but it's ugly.

```
if [ -z $outfile ]
then
    echo "$outbuf"    # Write output buffer to the screen (stdout)
else
    echo "$outbuf" > $outfile  # Write output buffer to file
fi
```

I tried to have the variable `$outfile` to be equal to `stdout`, to `&1` and perhaps something else but it would just write to file having that name and not actually to stdout. Is there a more elegant solution?

(*) I could cheat and use `stderr` for that purpose, but I think it's also quite ugly, isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you should [avoid `echo` to output arbitrary data](/q/65803).

On systems other than Linux-based ones, you could use:

```
logfile=/dev/stdout
```

For Linux, that works for some types of stdout, but that fails when stdout is a socket or worse, if stdout is a regular file, that would truncate that file instead of writing at the current position stdout is in the file.

Other than that, in Bourne-like shell, there's no way to have *conditional* redirection, though you could use `eval`:

```
eval 'printf "%s\n" "$buf" '${logfile:+'> "$logfile"'}
```

Instead of a *variable*, you could use a dedicated *file descriptor*:

```
exec 3>&1
[ -z "$logfile" ] || exec 3> "$logfile"

 printf '%s\n' "$buf" >&3
```

A (small) downside with that is that except in `ksh`, that fd 3 would be leaked to every command run in the script. With `zsh`, you can do `sysopen -wu 3 -o cloexec -- "$logfile" || exit` in place of `exec 3> "$logfile"` but `bash` has no equivalent.

Another common idiom is to use a function like:

```
log() {
  if [ -n "$logfile" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >> "$logfile"
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
  fi
}

log "$buf"
```

Comment: So basically, using `/dev/stdout` works in some case, but is not a good idea or can be problematic in some cases, then I'm better off doing the ugly if/else solution ?!

Comment: @Bregalad Looks like it.

Comment: Very nicely done with that example of a log file that shouldn't be truncated.

Comment: I do not understand this syntax : `[ -z "$logfile" ] || exec 3> "$logfile"` It looks like some shorthand if/then/else. Would you care to explain ? Thanks.

Comment: @Bregalad `||` is _or_. Either `$logfile` is empty _or_ you run the `exec` command. Check your shell man page.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So basically, `[ A ] || B` is just a shorthand for `if [ ! A ]; then B; fi` that have absolutely nothing to do with boolean logic or, right ?

Comment: @Bregalad, `A || B` is a bit like `if ! A; then B; fi` in that it executes the B command only if the A command returns false (note that you can use any command in the condition part of an `if` statement, not just the `[` command). It has everything to do with boolean logic. It's just that in shells, booleans are the exit status of commands (0 for true, anything else for false). The `[` command exits with 0 when the test expression it evaluates resolves to true. You can do `if A || B; then echo Either A or B returned true; fi` for instance (B would not be run if A returned true, like in C).

Answer (score 6):

1. Set `outfile` to `"/dev/stdout"`.
2. Let user choose filename, overriding `outfile`, or keep default value.
3. `printf '%s\n' "$outbuf" >"$outfile"`

I used `printf` because of "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)".

For caveats to this solution, see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336256/116858).

Comment: Completely agree. I'd do it the same way.

Comment: Beware on Linux-based systems, using `/dev/stdout` like that is a bad idea (see my answer)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas As always, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
TOSCREEN="1" # empty OR 0 to log to file
if [[ ! -z "$TOSCREEN" && $TOSCREEN == "1" ]]; then
    echo "$outbuf"    # Write output buffer to the screen (stdout)
else
    if [[ ! -f $outfile ]]; then
      #echo -e "Making file "
      touch "$outfile"
    fi  
    echo "$outbuf" >> $outfile  # Write output buffer to file
fi
```

Comment: Why go through the process of using `touch` and then appending?

Comment: you are right .

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

function stdout_or_file()
{
    DUMP_FILE=${1:-}

    if [ -z "${DUMP_FILE}" ]; then
        # print stdin to stdout
        cat
    else
        # dump stdin to a file
        sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"
    fi
}

echo "foo" | stdout_or_file "${outfile}"
```

Note that `${1:-}` is bash specific and especially useful in "-u" mode. A generic one-line that even works in other shells might be

```
echo "foo" | if [ -z "${outfile}" ]; then cat; else sed -n "w ${outfile}"; fi
```

Comment: `${1:-}` is actually POSIX standard, not `bash` specific. Using `-u` with `sh` (or with `set -u`) is also standard.

Comment: So are you using a non-POSIX shell then and that explains why you get a `-` there?

Comment: No I'm not, I'm instead not reading or thinking properly in the middle of the night in my +30 degree apartment. My apologies.  I've deleted the irrelevant comments.