# How to conditionally redirect the output to files based on variable in bash

Tags: bash, eval

I'm trying to use eval command to eval a comment -- I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. Example:

`i=??` (What I want here is either a `#`, to comment what's after, or blank)

`somecommand arg1 arg2 $(eval $i) >> file`

So based on the `$i` value it has to be either:

`somecommand arg1 arg2 # >> file` as of "Don't print to file"

or

`somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file` as of "Print to file"

An example script for more clarity:

```
i=true

somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file1
[some code]
somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file2
[some code]
somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file3
[some code]
And so on...
```

I want it to print the output to the files only if `$i` it true; or, as I tried at first, to `eval` the $i to be a comment and comment the 'output to file' piece of code.

I asked because I think there is a more elegant way than doing something like this:

```
if $i
then
   somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file3
else
   somecommand arg1 arg2
fi
```

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Instead of asking about a specific solution to your problem, I suggest you instead ask about the problem you're trying to solve.  It sounds like that problem is: _How do I conditionally redirect output to a file?_  Is that correct?

Comment: ... [Elegant solution to echo to either stdout or file in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336224/elegant-solution-to-echo-to-either-stdout-or-file-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver , but that's, not the answer I'm looking for, I want it to print based on a variable, keep in mind there are a lot of files to print to, not only one file

Comment: The answer @steeldriver referenced enables your use case.

Comment: `eval` is a last resort approach, especially for non-experts. So you should explain clearly why you think the linked answer is not suitable for you.

Comment: I have edited the post, i hope the example made it clear @HaukeLaging

Comment: How portable do you need this to be ? Are you working only on Linux or do you intend to target other operating systems, like BSD , MAC OS, AIX ?

Comment: And it's still somewhat unclear what you're trying to achieve.  I noticed you're using `somecommand` multiple times in your example, so this is same command , just writing to different files each time ? Or `somecommand` in `somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file1` is different from `somecommand` in `somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file2`  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always do:

```
unset -v log
# or
log=true
([ -z "$log" ] || exec >> file1; somecommand arg1 arg2)
([ -z "$log" ] || exec >> file2; somecommand arg1 arg2)
```

Or:

```
if [ -n "$log" ]; then
  exec 3>> file1 4>> file2
else
  exec 3>&1 4>&1
fi
somecommand arg1 arg2 >&3
somecommand arg1 arg2 >&4
```

Or:

```
log() {
  local output="$1"; shift
  if [ -n "$output" ]; then
    "$@" >> "$output"
  else
    "$@" 
  fi
}

log "${log+file1}" somecommand arg1 arg2
log "${log+file2}" somecommand arg1 arg2
```

Or (make sure the data passed to `eval` is not dynamic to avoid code injection vulnerabilities, hence the use of single quotes below inside which no expansion occurs):

```
eval ${log+'>> file1'} 'somecommand arg1 arg2'
eval ${log+'>> file2'} 'somecommand arg1 arg2'
```

With `zsh`:

```
if (($+log)); then
  alias -g 'log?=>>'
else
  alias -g 'log?=#'
fi

somecommand arg1 arg2 log? file1
somecommand arg1 arg2 log? file2
```

Or even (if you don't intend to use `>>` for anything other than that kind of conditional logging):

```
(($+log)) || alias -g '>>=#'

somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file1
somecommand arg1 arg2 >> file2
```

`bash` doesn't have `alias -g`, doesn't let you alias things like `>>`, but you could use simple `alias`es if you move the redirection to the start:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
skip_one() { shift; "$@"; }
if [[ -v log ]]; then
  alias 'log?=>>'
else
  alias 'log?=skip_one'
fi

log? file1 somecommand arg1 arg2
log? file2 somecommand arg1 arg2
```